# Vertically center text on page

Tags: html, css

I'm having trouble to get a div (or the text inside) to get on the vertical center. Normally I have no trouble getting a div to be a certain percentage from the top of a page, but in some weird way, the `%` part gets completely ignored.

Here's a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y1muc7gr/)

It's a very dumbed down version of my project, but it still screws up with the `margin-top`.

The result I'm aiming for is having the big text in the vertical middle of the page at all times. I have a feeling I'm actually approaching this completely wrong.

**HTML**

```
<div class="col-md-12 top-text">
    <span class="top-title">Billetten <br /> Tjekliste</span>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.top-text {
    text-align: center;
    color: #000;
    height: 10px;
    margin-top:50%;
}

span.top-title {
    font-family: 'art', helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 180px;
    line-height: 1em;
    display: inline-block;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-10deg) skew(-10deg, 0);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-10deg) skew(-10deg, 0);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-10deg) skew(-10deg, 0);
    -o-transform: rotate(-10deg) skew(-10deg, 0);
    transform: rotate(-10deg) skew(-10deg, 0);
}
```

Comment: [this](http://css-tricks.com/centering-in-the-unknown/) should help

Comment: Always do a search before you ask questions.

Comment: Trust me, I've done my part of searching, but none of the examples and answers I found, actually solved it :|

Comment: Depending on your browser support requirements, using [Flexbox](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) would be a clean solution.

Comment: Something like http://jsfiddle.net/y1muc7gr/1/ ?

Comment: Yes @JonasGrumann! Exactly that :D If you add that as an answer, I'll accept it. (including an explanation :)

Comment: I answered. I hope the explanation is clear enough, if not, ask again.

Comment: Try adding transform-origin: 0 0;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I usually do to center stuff vertically, is set their position to absolute, give it a top value of 50% and then drag them up again by translating them with a negative 50% (referred to their own width).

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/y1muc7gr/1/

```
span.top-title {
    font-family: 'art', helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 180px;
    line-height: 1em;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    width: 100%;
    -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
        -moz-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
        -o-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
        transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-10deg) skew(-10deg, 0) translateY(-50%);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-10deg) skew(-10deg, 0) translateY(-50%);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-10deg) skew(-10deg, 0) translateY(-50%);
    -o-transform: rotate(-10deg) skew(-10deg, 0) translateY(-50%);
    transform: rotate(-10deg) skew(-10deg, 0) translateY(-50%);
}
```

Comment: It's a bad joke that vertically centering stuff is still a pain in the ass after so many years of css and browser development.

Answer (score 0):

You are forgetting to minus the half text's height.

http://jsfiddle.net/y1muc7gr/2/

```
.top-text {
text-align: center;
color: #000;
height: 10px;
margin-top:-180px;
position: absolute;
top : 50%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

is that what you want?
i have make this jsfiddle
add position:relative in top-title
and bottom:200px;  change it according to your desired position

```
span.top-title {
position:relative;
font-family: 'art', helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
font-size: 180px;
line-height: 1em;
display: inline-block;
-webkit-transform: rotate(-10deg) skew(-10deg, 0);
-moz-transform: rotate(-10deg) skew(-10deg, 0);
-ms-transform: rotate(-10deg) skew(-10deg, 0);
-o-transform: rotate(-10deg) skew(-10deg, 0);
transform: rotate(-10deg) skew(-10deg, 0);
bottom:200px;
```

}

http://jsfiddle.net/y1muc7gr/5/

Answer (score 0):

[jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/y1muc7gr/4/)

setting the container with table-cell you can give it the vertical align properties to center the text inside.

```
.top-text {
    text-align: center;
    color: #000;
    height: 600px;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

the only problem is that you should have a fixed height container.